# Comic book about guy dreaming and waking up

Tags: story-identification, comics

I am looking for the name of a specific comic book.

There is a comic book about a guy having dreams and waking up at the end of each story.

A story would always be one page with everything being a dream that the guy had and the last panel would be the guy waking up. Waking up would mostly be triggered by looking into a mirror.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. a) Is there a science fiction or fantasy element to this story? I don't think that simply being in a comic book makes it on-topic. b) Your question could use some more detail. Perhaps something [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) would jog your memory, and then you could [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/184640/edit) the question to include those details.

Comment: This sounds a lot like Little Nemo, though Nemo usually wakes up due to falling from his bed.

Comment: @Politank-Z I think that a story that takes place mainly within dreams can be classified as fantasy, as long as what happens within the dreams is different from what might happen in the real world.  Still, more details would be good.